# How did this huge hole form?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, as you can see here, I have this hollow and wide hole! I know a Creeper didn't blow it up, because of this.

- The bottom is really smooth,
- I'm in Creative Mode
- My game is set to peaceful.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an example of a [basin](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Basin). A basin is essentially an area of land **not** covered by grass, therefore exposing things such as dirt, gravel and ores. Your basin looks like it's pretty small, but I've seen ones that small before. Here's an example of a **large** generated basin.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft-zh.gamepedia.com/0/08/Biomes_Basin.png))</sub>

Comment: To confirm this, hit F3 to turn on debug mode.  Your current biome will be displayed in the upper left.

Comment: @TimCoker Off to find a basin biome!

Comment: FYI, The easiest way to do find a specific biome (I've done it for a jungle so I could has kitty) when playing single player is to get your game's seed, then plug that in to AMIDST.  It will show the biomes and where they exist.  I would suggest, depending on how you want to play, to load a random seed and TURN OFF showing temples, strongholds and villages.  Once you do that, you can plug in your game's seed and not have anything spoiled.  Aside from there's that biome i want to visit off to the north east...

Comment: The source you provided doesn't support "basin" being a biome: "Basins can appear in any biome." Furthermore, in the [gamepedia wiki's article on "Biome"](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Biome), there is no reference to a basin biome existing.

Comment: Definitely not a *biome*.

Comment: @TimCoker No, it does not say the biome is a basin. I can confirm though that this is an "official" biome, as it has been in the game since alpha. If it was a bug, it would have been removed by now.

Comment: @UnionHawk Well, biome or not, it's been in the game since alpha, so, it has to be something. Right?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms I'm not denying that it's a thing, however, if you stand over a patch of naturally generated exposed stone and hit "F3", you will not see "Basin" where the F3 screen tells you what biome you are in.

Comment: @UnionHawk Removed "biome" from my answer, due to it appearing to not be a biome.

Comment: Basin is generated structure.

Answer (score -3):

It seems to be normal. I looked up caves on the Minecraft Wiki, and it showed a photo around the middle on the page, showing "An above ground circular cave" that looked like the one in your photo. It has some resemblance to your photo, but it was a bit bigger. Nothing weird. Naturally generated.

Answer (score -5):

It is a [Circular Room](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cave#Circular_rooms) that is created "above" ground

Comment: This is not a circular room, due to it not having any depth.

Comment: Do you mean the roof is missing? I think the room was created and then the ground so the roof disappeared.

Comment: I still have a hard time believing that this is a circular room.